# Trying to split a very large file into multiple smaller files based on the contents of each record (perl/linux)

Tags: linux, perl, sorting, split, large-files

Here is the problem.

I have 20 very large files, each approx 10gb, and I need to split each of the bulk files by A) criteria within the record and B) what type of bulk file it is.

Example.

Each bulk file represents an occupation. We have Lawyers, Doctors, Teachers and Programmers. Each of these bulk files contain millions of records for different individuals, not a lot of individuals, say 40 different people in total.

A record in the doctor file may look like

```
XJOHN 1234567   LOREMIPSUMBLABLABLA789
```

I would need this record from the file to be output into a file called `JOHN.DOCTOR.7`

John is the persons name, 7 is the last digit in the numeric sequence, and DOCTOR was the file type. I need to do this for file size limitations. Currently, I'm using perl to read the bulk files line by line and print the record into the appropriate output file. I'm opening a new handler for each record to avoid having multiple threads writing to the same handler and causing data malformations. I do have the program threaded, one thread per bulk file. I cannot install any third party applications, assume I only have whatever comes standard with RedHat Linux. I'm looking for either a Linux command that has a more efficient way of doing this or perhaps a better way that perl offers.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you really want a relational database (some database systems can scale well to 200GB), not a file system. Anyway, what actual problem do you have? This is just an issue of looping through the lines of the large file, for each line creating the target filename, and appending the line. It would make sense to keep  opened filehandles in a hash with the filenames as keys. If you already have working code, but want a review of that code, look at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You definitely should hire a programmer…

Comment: Why one thread per file?  How many cores do you have?  Having too many threads is not helpful and can even your performance due to overhead.

Comment: I am a programmer. I'm just looking for advice from other people who may have a better approach. 4 of these -> Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 2.80GHz. By threading these processes I've reduced the time this process has taken from 3 weeks to 3 days, but I'm looking to reduce this further. I considered a hash with file handles, and have done this previously, but using this I actually reach the number of files in a directory. There are 40 'occupations' if you will.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to use processes instead of threads, via [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager)

Additionally, I would consider using a map/reduce approach by giving each process/thread its own work directory, in which it would write intermediate files, one per doctor, lawyer, etc.

I would then write a second program, the reducer, which could be a very short shell script, to concatenate the intermediate files into their respective final output files.

Comment: +1 for using intermediate output files which are later joined

Comment: avoids the hassles of locking files and synchronizing threads. Thanks.